# Ubuntu 16.04 dual monitor resolution problem with dell precision 5510

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

i was installed ubuntu 16.04, my laptop is dell precision 5510

graphics are intel 530 and nvidia quadro m1000m

and using dual monitor that resolution 1920x1080

kernel version 4.4.11 xenial, 'xrandr' is below screenshot:

[image]

but connect external monitor by hdmi cable

panel and font size too enlargement in external monitor

then execute 'gnome-tweak-tool', in window of menu that modified configuration window scaling 2 to 1 then

being so, laptop monitor its too small font and panel

Is there someone to help for this problem?